# View Flow Usage and Flow Event Data Permission is conflicting across orgs

Tags: deployment, permissions, profile

I noticed today that a permission conflict is resulting in the failure of a deployment and we have no clear way to fix it.

The standard admin profile in Production has the `View Flow Usage and Flow Event Data` setting set to true, but our only full QA sandbox is set to false and causes deployments to fail to this org.

> You may not modify the permission View Flow Usage and Flow Event Data while editing a Standard Profile

Since this a full sandbox we don't have a window to refresh it from production. We also don't have the ability to change the setting in production as it's uneditable.

How did this conflict emerge and is there any possible way to fix it?

Comment: interesting, in our, Profile `System Administrator` permission `View Flow Usage and Flow Event Data` is false in PROD and all orgs.  As you noted it is uneditable.  Perhaps at one time, SFDC Support was engaged to enable it in PROD or there was an errant setting of this permission during an SFDC release. I'd call Support ; see also https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000isu4QAA

Comment: @cropredy I submitted a case with Salesforce and they confirmed it is a bug